# Не получается сделать push на Github, кнопка force push тоже не работает

Tags: git, intellij-idea, github, ide, git-push

Не получается сделать push из IDEA на Github выдает ошибку:

```html
12:36:42.526: [JavaRushTasks] git -c credential.helper= -c core.quotepath=false -c log.showSignature=false push --progress --porcelain origin refs/heads/master:master
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/Andrej-Prokudenko/JavaRushTasks.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
To https://github.com/Andrej-Prokudenko/JavaRushTasks.git
!   refs/heads/master:refs/heads/master [rejected] (non-fast-forward)
Done
hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g.
hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
12:36:47.942: [JavaRushTasks] git -c credential.helper= -c core.quotepath=false -c log.showSignature=false fetch origin --recurse-submodules=no --progress --prune
12:36:49.364: [JavaRushTasks] git -c credential.helper= -c core.quotepath=false -c log.showSignature=false reset --hard --
error: unable to unlink old 'out.log': Invalid argument
fatal: Could not reset index file to revision 'HEAD'.
12:36:49.635: [JavaRushTasks] git -c credential.helper= -c core.quotepath=false -c log.showSignature=false merge origin/master --no-stat -v
fatal: refusing to merge unrelated histories
```

Хотел сделать force push, но не активна кнопка force push в меню IDEA
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: а прочитать сообщение, в котором прямо указано что нужно сделать, не получается?

Comment: Вопрос в том, почему может быть не активна кнопка  force push, а не в сообщении

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема решилась перезаливкой проекта и исключением из последующих коммитов файла "out.log".